# How can I use #tags in pager_default_initialize()?

Tags: 8, theming

I want different label for first/last/next/previous button in the custom navigation using  pager_default_initialize(). How I can set an array that can change the button label.

```
$total_count =9999;
$page = pager_default_initialize($total_count, 30,$tags );
$pager = [
  '#type' => 'pager',
];
```

This give a pagination like :

```
« First ‹ Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 … Next › Last »
```

I want pagination like :

```
« pratham ‹ pichhala 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 … aage › antim »
```

Comment: I'm wondering are you talking about translation?

Comment: @leymannz No I just give an example. not looking for translation. how pagination label I want

Comment: Did you enable Twig debugging? Can you see what templates are used for the pager? Are these strings hard-coded in there maybe? Or can you preprocess them via `MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(&$variables)`?

Comment: What about the "#tags" thing in the title? Or is your question rather: "How can I rename pager labels?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copy [`core/modules/system/templates/pager.html.twig`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.10/core/modules/system/templates/pager.html.twig) to `themes/custom/MYTHEME/templates/page.html.twig` and rename the labels. Flush cache. Twice.

If they are still English leave the `|t` or if they are in a language other than English remove the `|t` and note that they then ain't translatable anymore.

You should have found out about the location of the exact template in use when you [enable Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates#s-enable-debugging). You then can inspect the name and location of the current template as HTML comments directly in the markup in your browser.

---

Alternatively use a preprocess hook to rename the labels dynamically:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_pager().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['items']['first']) {
    $variables['items']['first']['text'] = t('Yeah first page');
  }
  if ($variables['items']['previous']) {
    $variables['items']['previous']['text'] = t('Yeah previous page');
  }
  if ($variables['items']['next']) {
    $variables['items']['next']['text'] = t('Yeah next page');
  }
  if ($variables['items']['last']) {
    $variables['items']['last']['text'] = t('Yeah last page');
  }
}
```